# libinput: delay between touch and button release, making it hard to release a drag and drop

Tags: touchpad, libinput

I'm using libinput (on nixos 20.03/KDE plasma 5.17 with default configuration), and I've a quite annoying behaviour: when I untouch my touchpad during a selection or a drag and drop, the click is not release directly, and I need to wait ~0.3 seconds to see the click released.

While it may seem minor, it's very annoying, because if I click again, it continues the old selection/drag and drop like if I never released my button. Therefore, if I select something, and want to click on a button right after to perform an action for example, I will in fact change my selection.

Any idea how to change that behaviour?

Thanks!

EDIT:
To answer to Hi-Angel, I do have these messages without delay:

```
 event18  POINTER_MOTION   +12.343s       0.88/  0.00 ( +1.00/ +0.00)
 event18  POINTER_MOTION   +12.352s       0.88/  0.00 ( +1.00/ +0.00)
event18 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_AREA    event BUTTON_EVENT_UP          to BUTTON_STATE_NONE   
event18 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_NONE    event BUTTON_EVENT_IN_AREA     to BUTTON_STATE_AREA
 event18  POINTER_MOTION   +12.524s       0.00/  0.88 ( +0.00/ +1.00)
 event18  POINTER_MOTION   +12.541s       0.00/  0.86 ( +0.00/ +1.00)
```

and I'm using libinput 1.15.0.

Comment: Possibly this may be caused by libinput_device_config_tap_set_drag_lock_enabled() feature, which sets delay before releasing. libinput settings have different implementations in Wayland WMs / X11.

Comment: It may be a problem in libinput or elsewhere in the stack. Please run `libinput debug-events --verbose`, start selection with touchpad, and then release it while looking at the output. You should see something like `button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_AREA    event BUTTON_EVENT_UP          to BUTTON_STATE_NONE` or maybe `BTN_LEFT (272) released` appear. If there's the delay you mention before it appears, then it's likely the libinput problem. While on it: what libinput version do you have?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, it was indeed due to drag lock as seen by @chzzh. Thanks a lot, feel free to write or copy paste my answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by chzzh in comments, it is actually a feature, not a bug. I don't like that feature, which is enabled by default on NixOs, so I disabled it.

To temporary disable it, first get the id of the touch pad by looking at the list here:

```
$ xinput list
```

then run (after replacing `ID_OF_TOUCHPAD` with the corresponding id):

```
xinput --set-prop ID_OF_TOUCHPAD "libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled" 0
```

(you can see the full list of options for a particular device with `xinput list-props ID_OF_TOUCHPAD`)

On Nixos, to disable it permanently, you just need to put in your `configuration.nix` the following:

```
services.xserver.libinput.touchpad.tappingDragLock = false;
```

Note that it seems that you need to reboot to see the changes applied, and this option has been renamed: on older NixOs you might need `services.xserver.libinput.tappingDragLock = false;` instead.

On other systems, I think it's disabled by default, but you may want to change X11 options as [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-20.03/nixos/modules/services/x11/hardware/libinput.nix#L236).

Comment: Also try setting "Evdev Debounce Delay" to 0. This worked for me, as the other one was already 0.

Comment: Setting services.xserver.libinput.tappingDragLock (renamed to services.xserver.libinput.touchpad.tappingDragLock) to false worked for me on NixOS 22.11.

Comment: @LasseHalbergHaarbye thanks, I updated the answer.